# Node running ESM - ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs, claudiajs

Really struggling with this.  I'm trying to run ESM scripts on Node 14 (AWS Lamda)

I'm trying to run [this code](https://gist.github.com/mrdoob/44c1473ecb6cd636deeaa93a1bb7475e#file-fbx2three-js) to convert 3D objects to THREE JSON.

This requires `node -r esm fbx2three.js model.fbx` to run.

I think I can do it with this approach I found in [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-ecmascript-modules-with-node-js/) blog

i.e.

**Index.ts**

```
import Convert from './runner.js'
```

**Runner.js**

```
require = require("esm")(module);
module.exports = require("./converter.mjs").default;
```

**Converter.mjs**

```
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js'

export default function convertObj(url){
    const loader = new OBJLoader()
    const json = loader.parse(url).toJSON()
}
```

I'm now stuck on this error when it compiles

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

ReferenceError: exports is not defined

From converter.mjs:2:29
```

Which compiled to

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const OBJLoader_js_1 = require("three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js");
function convertObj(url) {
    const loader = new OBJLoader_js_1.OBJLoader();
    const json = loader.parse(url).toJSON();
}
exports.default = convertObj;
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./bin",   
    "rootDir": "./src", 
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "target": "es6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

**Package**

```
{
  "name": "converter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "update": "tsc && claudia update  --handler bin/index.handler --timeout 60 --memory 1024",
    "create": "tsc && claudia create --region ap-southeast-2 --handler bin/index.handler",
    "pack": "tsc && claudia pack --api-module bin/index --force",
    "test": "claudia test-lambda --event event.json"
  },
  "main": "bin/index",
  "files": [
    "bin/**/*.*",
    "package.json"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "s3-unzip": "^0.1.13",
    "three": "^0.135.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.11.11",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "claudia": "^5.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What file does your error originate from (look at the stack trace)?

Comment: converter.mjs:2:29 - thanks added the error to hte post

Comment: Your ".mjs" file is actually cjs and then you're trying to use it from an esm module so of course it doesn't work. Change your tsconfig to output esm instead of commonjs.

Comment: Thanks. I know nothing about mjs or cjs.. but going to try something else so if that doens't work will try this. Pretty sure I need commonjs to run on AWS Lamda?

Comment: @beek depends on the version of nodejs. Also when responding to people's comments be sure to @ them, the system doesn't necessarily notify us of your response if you don't. Quick rundown: when nodejs was created there was no Javascript module system so they invented one (commonjs aka cjs). But it wasn't suitable for use in the browser, so there was a standard proposed (esm aka mjs) that got adopted by browsers. So now there are 2 (actually more yikes). Nodejs recently added support for esm, but it doesn't interop well with cjs. I recommend just sticking with cjs if you can.

Comment: In esm/mjs you use `export` and `import`, and in cjs you use `require` and `module.exports`. There are also some other subtle differences like modules being automatically evaluated in strict mode, how default exports are handled, etc. It's admittedly a complete mess. You can use a compiler like babel or tsc (if using typescript) to convert the import/export syntax to cjs.

Answer (score 0):

Try making both false (or remove),

- esModuleInterop
- allowSyntheticDefaultImports

Comment: 3 import Convert from './runner.js'
         ~~~~~~~

  src/runner.js:3:1
    3 module.exports = require("./converter.mjs/index.js").default;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.

Comment: Won't let me import 2 import aws either - aws has no default export.